# How to rreturn a nested serialized data in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I created a `Registration` view in my Django app, but when I tried testing it, I wasn't getting the expected result.

I'm trying to test my view with the data below, but I wasn't getting the expected result:

```
{   
    "email": "faruqmohammad@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "Faruq",
    "last_name": "Mohahmmad",
    "phone_number": "08137021976",
    "password": "#FaruqMohammad1234",
    "confirm_password": "#FaruqMohammad1234",
    "vehicle_registration_number": "ABJ145",
    "min_capacity": 20,
    "max_capacity": 50,
    "fragile_item_allowed": true,
    "charge_per_mile": 1000
}
```

And the response I get is

```
{
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "email": "mohammedfaruq@gmail.com",
            "first_name": "Mohammed",
            "last_name": "Faruq",
            "phone_number": "08137021976"
        },
        "is_available": true,
        "vehicle_type": "TWO_WHEELER",
        "vehicle_registration_number": "",
        "min_capacity": null,
        "max_capacity": null,
        "fragile_item_allowed": true,
        "ratings": null,
        "charge_per_mile": null
    },
    "message": "Rider registration successful"
}
```

```json
{
  "vehicle_registration_number": "",  
  "min_capacity": null, 
  "max_capacity": null, 
  "fragile_item_allowed": true,         
  "ratings": null, 
  "charge_per_mile": null
}
```

These values are set to the default value from the model even when I provided them

And below is my model, serializer and views

Model:

```
class Rider(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="rider_profile"
    )
    vehicle_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="TWO_WHEELER")
    vehicle_registration_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    min_capacity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    max_capacity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    fragile_item_allowed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    charge_per_mile = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True
    )
    current_latitude = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, null=True, blank=True
    )
    current_longitude = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, null=True, blank=True
    )
    ratings = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email

    def update_location(self, latitude, longitude):
        self.current_latitude = latitude
        self.current_longitude = longitude
        self.save()
```

Serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for the CustomUser model. It includes custom validation for the password
    and email fields
    """

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = [
            "email",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "phone_number",
            "password",
            "confirm_password",
        ]

    def validate_password(self, value):
        # Password must be at least 8 characters long
        if len(value) < 8:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Password must be at least 8 characters long."
            )

        # Check for at least one uppercase character
        if not any(char.isupper() for char in value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Password must contain at least one uppercase character."
            )

        # Check for at least one special character
        special_characters = "!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}|;:'\",.<>/?"
        if not any(char in special_characters for char in value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Password must contain at least one special character."
            )

        # Check for at least one number
        if not any(char.isdigit() for char in value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Password must contain at least one number."
            )
        return value

    def validate_email(self, value):
        if CustomUser.objects.filter(email=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This email is already in use.")
        return value

    def validate(self, data):
        # Check if password and confirm_password match
        password = data.get("password")
        confirm_password = data.get("confirm_password")
        logger.debug({password, confirm_password})
        if password != confirm_password:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Passwords do not match.")
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Remove 'confirm_password' from the data before creating the user
        validated_data.pop("confirm_password", None)

        # Retrieve password directly from validated_data
        password = validated_data.get("password")

        # Ensure that password is not None before validating its length
        if password is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Password cannot be empty.")

        self.validate_password(password)

        # Create the user without 'confirm_password'
        user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

        # Set the password for the user
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user


class CustomUserNestedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = (
            "email",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "phone_number",
        )



class RiderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = CustomUserNestedSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Rider
        fields = [
            "user",
            "is_available",
            "vehicle_type",
            "vehicle_registration_number",
            "min_capacity",
            "max_capacity",
            "fragile_item_allowed",
            "ratings",
            "charge_per_mile",
        ]
```

And Views:

```
class BaseUserRegistrationView(APIView):
    user_model = None
    serializer_class = None

    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Log the request data
        logger.debug(f"Request_data: {request.data}")

        # Extract the user data from the request
        user_data = request.data

        # Validate the user data using the UserSerializer
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=user_data)

        if user_serializer.is_valid():
            # Access the validated data after validation
            user_data = user_serializer.validated_data

            if user_data:
                try:
                    with transaction.atomic():
                        # Save the user and create a user object
                        user = user_serializer.save()
                        user_obj = self.user_model.objects.create(user=user)

                        # Serialize the user object
                        user_obj_serializer = self.serializer_class(user_obj).data

                        if user_obj_serializer:
                            # Send a welcome email or perform any additional actions
                            send_verification_email(user, "registration")

                            # Return a response with the serialized user object and a success message
                            return Response(
                                {
                                    "data": user_obj_serializer,
                                    "message": f"{self.user_model.__name__} registration successful",
                                },
                                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                            )
                        else:
                            # Raise a validation error if the user serializer is not valid
                            return Response(
                                {
                                    "detail": "Validation error",
                                    "errors": user_serializer.errors,
                                },
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                            )

                except IntegrityError as e:
                    # Handle integrity errors
                    logger.error(f"Integrity error: {e}")
                    return Response(
                        {
                            "detail": "Integrity error. Please ensure the data is unique."
                        },
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                    )
                except Exception as e:
                    # Handle unexpected errors
                    logger.error(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
                    return Response(
                        {"detail": "An unexpected error occurred."},
                        status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    )
        else:
            # Raise a validation error if the user serializer is not valid
            return Response(
                {"detail": "Validation error", "errors": user_serializer.errors},
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )


class RiderRegistrationView(BaseUserRegistrationView):
    user_model = Rider
    serializer_class = RiderSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code structure for the `Rider` registration view involves a complex inheritance hierarchy, particularly with values not being set correctly. I suggest refactoring your code for clarity and better adherence to Django/DRF best practices.

Here's an improved version of your serializers and views:

**Serializers:**

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = (
            "email",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "phone_number",
        )


class RiderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    # User Related Fields
    email = serializers.EmailField(write_only=True, validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=CustomUser.objects.all())])
    first_name = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

    # Rider Related Fields
    vehicle_registration_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=20, validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=Rider.objects.all())])
    min_capacity = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    max_capacity = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    fragile_item_allowed = serializers.BooleanField(default=True)
    charge_per_mile = serializers.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, required=False, allow_null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Rider
        fields = (
            'user', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number',
            'password', 'confirm_password', 'vehicle_type', 'vehicle_registration_number',
            'is_available', 'min_capacity', 'max_capacity', 'fragile_item_allowed',
            'ratings', 'charge_per_mile',
        )

    def validate(self, data):
        password = data.get('password')
        confirm_password = data.pop('confirm_password')
        if password != confirm_password:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Passwords do not match.")
        try:
            validate_password(password=password)
        except serializers.ValidationError as e:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(e)
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        rider_data = {
            'vehicle_registration_number': validated_data.pop('vehicle_registration_number', ''),
            'min_capacity': validated_data.pop('min_capacity', None),
            'max_capacity': validated_data.pop('max_capacity', None),
            'fragile_item_allowed': validated_data.pop('fragile_item_allowed', True),
            'charge_per_mile': validated_data.pop('charge_per_mile', None),
        }

        user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        rider = Rider.objects.create(user=user, **rider_data)

        return rider
```

**Views:**

```py
from rest_framework import generics


class RiderRegistrationView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RiderSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        data = {
            "message": "Rider registered successfully",
            "data": serializer.data,
        }
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

This refactoring simplifies your code structure, improves readability, and should help resolve the issues you mentioned.

**Please note that I haven't included all the functionality from your original code, but I hope this helps you get started.**

Comment: Great, thanks, I was able to get the expected result

Answer (score 0):

you can use "source" argument to avoid nested serialized data. here is an example of how to use it:

```
class ReporterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    email = serializers.EmailField(source='user.email')
        class Meta:
            model = Subscriber
            fields = ('username', 'email')
```

this is just a simple example. you can read more about it in django REST framework documants. here is the [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source). I hope this helps you.